# Adding ofstream method for object defined by typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

Let's say a define a custom type in my c++ code to handle vectors in 3d:

```
typedef tuple<double,double,double> vector3d;
```

Is it possible to add a method to that so that I can quickly output their coordinates using:

```
vector3d somevector(1,1,1);
cout << somevector << "\n";
```

I know I could do it wrapping these objects in a `class` or a `struct` but is it possible to do it more straightforwardly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload [streaming operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) for `ostream`.

```
typedef tuple<double,double,double> vector3d;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector3d& vec)
{
    os << '(' <<
          std::get<0>(vec) << ',' <<
          std::get<1>(vec) << ',' <<
          std::get<2>(vec) << ')';
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << vector3d(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is worth noticing that this operator will be called for all tuples with 3 doubles in it, ignoring the typedef